# Include folder of JSON files at build time

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular 12 application -- a dashboard for an embedded system -- relies on JSON files, which are used at runtime to generate forms etc.

Some files are known before compilation. I declared an interface to be able to type check their values in code, and added a `typings.d.ts` file to declare them as modules:

```
declare module 'params.json' {
  const value: IParams;
  export default value;
}
```

Then, in my services, I just include them that way:

```
import params from 'src/assets/data/params.json';
```

That way, I can avoid making asychronous HTTP calls to read the files. Instead, their content is included in my application at build time.

However, I have a problem with a folder of JSON files which can contain a varying number of files. I tried going the same way:

```
declare module 'sensors/*.json' {
  const value: ISensor;
  export default value;
}
```

But then, how would I be able to import the files?

In an ideal world, I'd like to get a `Record<string, ISensor>` with filenames as key, and JSON file contents as value.

Please ask me for more details if the question isn't clear enough.